# Grant Execute Permission to Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have been given 'Windows Authentication' access to our development database. However, I am unable to execute stored procedures in this db. The error that I'm getting is:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure XXP_LOAD_FACT, Line 1 The
>   EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'XXP_LOAD_FACT', database
>   'XXP_POC', schema 'dbo'.

I contacted the database owner and he replied back saying that the access had been given. But I still can't run any SPs.  He also said that if there are still issues, I can grant execute permission on the SP to my own ID. I was wondering how this can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms345484.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I followed the steps and performed what was required. But the changes are not getting saved, meaning when I close the 'Properties' dialog box and come back again, I cannot see the changes I have made.

Comment: I tried this:
'USE XXP_POC; 
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.XXP_LOAD_FACT
    TO [DOMAIN\USER_NAME]; -- My User Name
GO'

This is the error:

Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Comment: Have your owner do this: `execute as user = 'domain\user_name';select * from sys.fn_my_permissions('dbo.XXP_LOAD_FACT', 'OBJECT');revert;'`. If the result set that gets returned doesn't include "execute", you don't have execute. Tell them to get back to you when the above returns with an execute permission.